Movie about a burnt woman on life support system starts killing people with fire
I remember watching this movie in 2011. The movie was on Netflix but its no longer there.
It is about a married couple, they have an accident and the woman gets burnt horribly. The woman ends up on life support in the hospital, but at nights, she can get out of her body and starts killing people with fire. The husband cheats on her and it is revealed that he actually set her on fire during their car accident. At the end, the man skins his mistress alive so they can use her skin to perform surgery on the burnt wife but when he goes to the hospital she is already dead.

How old would you say it was? Was it American?

"Beneath" (2007) (Wikipedia, IMDb)
Plot:

Christy (Nora Zehetner) returns home years after a terrible auto accident, in which she was driving. That misfortunate event caused the disfigurement of her older sister. Now disturbing nightmares plague the young woman, and she finds that her visions reflect true and future events."

Preview:




It's called "Right to Die" it's from the Master's of Horror Collection.
Here is the links:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_Die_(Masters_of_Horror)
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0871197/
You can buy the video online. 
